# Scale plot size of Matplotlib Plots in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Is there a possibility to scale the plot size of matplotlib plots in jupyter notebooks? You could increase the plot size by changing the default values of `figure.figsize`, but this does not affect parameters like fontsize, linewidth, markersize etc. What I need is a plot where all the parameters are scaled accordingly.

P.S.: To display plots in jupyter notebooks I use `%matplotlib inline`, see screenshot below.

[image]

#### Edit

For completeness, here is a code snippet doing exactly what I needed:

```
def scale_plot_size(factor=1.5):
    import matplotlib as mpl
    default_dpi = mpl.rcParamsDefault['figure.dpi']
    mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = default_dpi*factor
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't want to change the figure size. You want to change the dpi (dots per inch).
Also see [Relationship between dpi and figure size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633546/relationship-between-dpi-and-figure-size?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def plot(dpi):
    fig, ax=plt.subplots(dpi=dpi)
    ax.plot([2,4,1,5], label="Label")
    ax.legend()

for i in range(1,4):
    plot(i*72)
```

[image]

Comment: Something like `import matplotlib as mpl` and `mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300` will work for setting the default.