# Increasing figure size in matplotlib causes all other formatting to be small

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am creating to some plots for explorartory analysis in matplotlib which I want to be significantly larger than the default 8x6 inches. I have tried using:

```
fig.set_size_inches(16, 12)
```

However, this does not scale any of the axes elements like ticks, titles etc. Is it possible to increase the size of the plot without having to manually set the size of all the other parameters?

Comment: This might be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633546/relationship-between-dpi-and-figure-size

Comment: This has helped me a lot.

Comment: Is there still anything left unclear from that linked thread, or can this be closed as duplicate?

Comment: close it id say, this question doesnt add anything