# How to make picture clear when saving the table of DataFrame as a picture

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to save the table of DataFrame as a picture and I get inspired from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png).
But sadly, the table picture I draw is so vague and I can't make it clear.
This is my environment:

> Python 3.7.0
>   pandas                             0.23.0
>   matplotlib                         2.2.2

And here is my code, its table and my picture:

```
train_corr
```

```
         Survived    Pclass      Age         SibSp       Parch      Fare
Survive  1.000000   -0.338481   -0.077221   -0.035322    0.081629    0.257307
Pclass  -0.338481    1.000000   -0.369226    0.083081    0.018443   -0.549500
Age     -0.077221   -0.369226    1.000000   -0.308247   -0.189119    0.096067
SibSp   -0.035322    0.083081   -0.308247    1.000000    0.414838    0.159651
Parch    0.081629    0.018443   -0.189119    0.414838    1.000000    0.216225
Fare     0.257307   -0.549500    0.096067    0.159651    0.216225    1.000000
```

```
from pandas.plotting import  table

ax = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=False) # no visible frame
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the y axis

table(ax, train_corr, loc='center')  

plt.savefig('correlation_matrix_HD.jpg')
```

[image]

And I have searched documentation about [pandas.plotting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-tools) and [matplotlib.pyplot.table](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html?highlight=table#matplotlib.pyplot.table), but I still don't know how to figure it out.
If not mind, could anyone help me?
Thanks sincerely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to play with the figure size and figure dpi

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frame_on=False)
```

change the values until you're satisfied. For the interplay between the two see [Relationship between dpi and figure size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47639545/4124317).

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the `dpi`  parameter in *[savefig()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)* to adjust the resolution of the plot.

From the documentation

> **dpi : [ None | scalar > 0 | 'figure' ]**
>
> The resolution in dots per inch. If None, defaults to
>   rcParams["savefig.dpi"].     If 'figure', uses the figure's dpi value.

```
plt.savefig('correlation_matrix_HD.jpg',dpi=600)
```

Play around with the `dpi` value to suit your need.