# Does varying extent in imshow() lead to changes in pixel number while rendering the image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pixel, imshow, extent

I went through the tutorial [origin and extent in imshow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html) and also through the documentation of [extent in imshow()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow). It was mentioned there that **pixels have unit size in data coordinates**,**their centers are on integer coordinates**. Hence varying the extent parameter should control the number of pixels in the rendered image. I want to verify this. My idea is to make a 10x10x3 RGB data-array and plot it using `imshow()` with default extent. Then plot the same data-array with `imshow()`, but modifying extent to ensure a higher number of pixels. I am stuck when I am required to verify if the two rendered images indeed have a difference of pixel count.

Below is the code to express the idea -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a 10x10x3 RGB data-array
x = np.linspace(1,10,10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
r = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
R = X/r
G = (np.sqrt(2*X*Y))/r
B = Y/r
data = np.stack([R,G,B],axis=-1)

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

# image with supposedly lower pixels
im1 = ax1.imshow(data,origin='lower')
ax1.set_title('Lower expected pixel')

# image supposedly higher pixels
im2 = ax2.imshow(data,origin='lower',extent=(-0.5,99.5,-0.5,99.5))
ax2.set_title('Higher expected pixel')
```

[image: Output]

My primary questions here are -

- **Is my guess "changing extent changes pixel count" correct?**
- **How to perform the verification that I referred to above?**

Comment: Extent only affects how the x and y axes are labeled, not the number of pixels.  The number of pixels is the size of the axes, in inches, times dpi.

Comment: @Jodi Klymak Thanks for the clarification. Based on your clarification, I searched the internet further and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633546/relationship-between-dpi-and-figure-size) discussion on dpi, which further clarifies things.