# How to change size of confusion matrix in fastai?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-visualization, confusion-matrix, fast-ai

I am drawing a Confusion Matrix in `fastai` with following code:

```
interp = ClassificationInterpretation.from_learner(learn)
interp.plot_confusion_matrix()
```

But I end up with a super small matrix because I have around 20 categories:

[image: small confusion matrix]

I have found the related question for sklearns but don't know how to apply it to fastai (because we don't use `pyplot` directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the code of the function `ClassificationInterpretation.plot_confusion_matrix` (in file *fastai / interpret.py*), this is what you see:

```
    def plot_confusion_matrix(self, normalize=False, title='Confusion matrix', cmap="Blues", norm_dec=2,
                              plot_txt=True, **kwargs):
        "Plot the confusion matrix, with `title` and using `cmap`."
        # This function is mainly copied from the sklearn docs
        cm = self.confusion_matrix()
        if normalize: cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        fig = plt.figure(**kwargs)
        plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
        plt.title(title)
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(self.vocab))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, self.vocab, rotation=90)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, self.vocab, rotation=0)
```

The key here is the line `fig = plt.figure(**kwargs)`, so basically, the function `plot_confusion_matrix` will propagate its parameters to the plot function.

So you could use either one of these:

- `dpi=xxx` (e.g. `dpi=200`)
- `figsize=(xxx, yyy)`

See this post on StackOverflow about the relations they have with each other:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47639545/1603480

So in your case, you could just do:

```
interp.plot_confusion_matrix(figsize=(12, 12))
```

And the Confusion Matrix would look like:

[image: big confusion matrix]

FYI: this also applies to other plot functions, like

```
interp.plot_top_losses(20, nrows=5, figsize=(25, 25))
```