# How to change figure size and other size elements for a svg file

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, svgutils

I am currently working with figures that I save in **SVG** format, in order to include them into a HTML presentation. I'm looking for consistency in terms of fonts, line sizes etc .. across the presentation.

Hence, I need to scale all my figures of a factor 2 in width compared to the default `matplotlib` params.

For now, I am relying on an external python lib, `svgutils`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import svgutils.transform as sg

figname = 'test.svg'
fig = plt.figure()
fig.savefig(figname)

fig = sg.fromfile(figname)
newsize = ['{}pt'.format(2 * float(i.replace('pt', ''))) for i in fig.get_size()]

fig.set_size(newsize)
fig.save(figname)
```

but this is a small project and I am not sure it will be maintained through time, so I'd like to do it only with `matplotlib`.

If I only modify the `figsize`, all other elements (i.e lines) do not increase in size. Is there a way to scale all parameters? Or should I go over each element defined in the `rcParams` and scale them appropriately? That looks rather long to do ...

EDIT: Note that changing the DPI (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633546/relationship-between-dpi-and-figure-size)) will not work, as SVG objects do not have associated DPI, unlike raster formats (i.e png, jpeg, etc ..).

Comment: Changing the `dpi` is probably the easiest way. See [`fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 5), dpi=100)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS1BE.png) compared to [`fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 5), dpi=200)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCrp0.png) compared to [`fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10), dpi=100)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJjap.png)

Comment: SVG figure does not have a DPI. Hence, changing the DPI does not affect the output when saving figures in SVG format. Please re-open the issue if you closed it.

Comment: My naive assumption is "When I scale the figure, in the HTML code that includes it, what is rendered is a figure where everything is scaled accordingly".  What do you need to be made differently?

Answer (score 0):

- Changing the DPI for SVGs from matplotlib will not work because SVGs are vector graphics and don't have a DPI in the same sense that raster graphics do.
- To achieve a consistent scaling of all elements in the plot, you must update the figure size, and various size-related parameters in `rcParams`.

  - Manually adjust the values with `rcParams`, or use a scaling factor, as follows.

    - Some size parameters are text, '`large'`, which will be replaced with the corresponding numeric value, and then scaled.
- Other resources:

  - [How to change the font size on a matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899980/7758804)
  - [Customizing Matplotlib with style sheets and rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/customizing.html)

    - **You may want to [define your own style](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/customizing.html#defining-your-own-style) in a file.**
  - [`matplotlib.rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rcParams)
- **Tested in `python 3.12.0`, `matplotlib 3.8.0`**

```py
# Check if value is numeric
def is_numeric(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

# Set up a scaling factor
scale_factor = 2
text_num = {'large': 12, 'medium': 10}

# List of rcParams to scale
params_to_scale = [
    'font.size', 
    'axes.titlesize', 
    'axes.labelsize', 
    'xtick.labelsize',
    'ytick.labelsize', 
    'legend.fontsize', 
    'legend.handlelength',  
    'axes.linewidth',
    'grid.linewidth',
    'lines.linewidth', 
    'lines.markersize',
    'patch.linewidth',
    'xtick.major.width',
    'ytick.major.width',
    'xtick.minor.width',
    'ytick.minor.width',
]

# Scale the relevant rcParams by the scaling factor
for param in params_to_scale:
    current_value = plt.rcParams[param]
    print(f'Before {param}: {current_value}')
    if is_numeric(current_value):
        plt.rcParams[param] *= scale_factor
    else:
        # replace text value with numeric value and apply scaling
        plt.rcParams[param] = text_num[current_value] * scale_factor
    print(f'After {param}: {plt.rcParams[param]}\n')
    

# Create a sample plot to test
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6 * scale_factor, 4 * scale_factor))
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], label="Sample Line")
ax.set_title("Sample Title")
ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
ax.grid(True)
ax.legend()

# Save the figure
fig.savefig('scaled_figure.svg')

# Reset the rcParams back to default (optional)
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
```

#### Printed Output

```
Before font.size: 10.0
After font.size: 20.0

Before axes.titlesize: large
After axes.titlesize: 24.0

Before axes.labelsize: medium
After axes.labelsize: 20.0

Before xtick.labelsize: medium
After xtick.labelsize: 20.0

Before ytick.labelsize: medium
After ytick.labelsize: 20.0

Before legend.fontsize: medium
After legend.fontsize: 20.0

Before legend.handlelength: 2.0
After legend.handlelength: 4.0

Before axes.linewidth: 0.8
After axes.linewidth: 1.6

Before grid.linewidth: 0.8
After grid.linewidth: 1.6

Before lines.linewidth: 1.5
After lines.linewidth: 3.0

Before lines.markersize: 6.0
After lines.markersize: 12.0

Before patch.linewidth: 1.0
After patch.linewidth: 2.0

Before xtick.major.width: 0.8
After xtick.major.width: 1.6

Before ytick.major.width: 0.8
After ytick.major.width: 1.6

Before xtick.minor.width: 0.6
After xtick.minor.width: 1.2

Before ytick.minor.width: 0.6
After ytick.minor.width: 1.2
```

#### `scale_factor = 2`

[image]

#### `scale_factor = 1`

[image]

<sup>Example images are png because svg is not supported on StackOverflow.</sup>

Comment: Yep, that is what I would like to avoid doing, because considering the number of parameters in rc files, one will always forget about some. For instance, the tick length has not been scaled up in your example. I will open an enhancement issue in the GitHub, and see what we can do about this.

Comment: The question was _Is there a way to scale all parameters? Or should I go over each element defined in the rcParams and scale them appropriately?_ and the answer was you need to scale them. That’s why it also links to the option to create a configuration file.

Comment: This is true, although many of them are lacking in the list you provided. When I have a bit more time, I will try to build an exhaustive list and leave it here for future reference.

Comment: It wasn’t meant to provide an exhaustive list, just to show how to do the scaling for numeric and string parameters